# Is it possible filterBy no values in emberjs?

Tags: ember.js, ember-controllers

In my controller, I have a filtered array like

```
filteredPosts: Ember.computed.filterBy('model', 'foo', 'bar')
```

Is it possible that filteredPosts does not filter anything  at all. I need this in case a user doesn't want to apply a filter and just wants to see all of the posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then don't use `Ember.computed.filterBy`. If you don't want to filter use the array directly. Or to implement something like a wildcard build your own computed property:

```
filteredPosts: Ember.computed('model', 'bar', {
    get() {
        const filter = this.get('bar');
        const model = this.get('model');
        return filter === '*' ? model : model.filterBy('foo', bar);
    }
})
```

Basically `Ember.computed.filterBy` is just syntactic sugar around a few lines of code. If you want to modify this code, just write it yourself.